# convert PHP DOMDocument to be readable as html tags.

Tags: php, html, domdocument

how do i convert elements that is created using DOMDocument to be readable as html?. if you run the code below the $appended will show the code like this = [image]

but what i am aiming is for it to be converted to html tags and to look like this. [image]

```
    <?php
        global $connection;
        $html = "<div id='suggested-video'> 
        <h2>Suggestion For you</h2>
        <ul>

        </ul>
        </div>";
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
        $doc->loadHTML($html);

        $sexy = 'sexy';
        $limit = 12;
        $isi = 1;
        $arrayz = array();
        $arrayz2 = array();
        $query = "SELECT `videoname`,`username`,`videourl`,`uploaddate`,`duration`,`views`,`tags`,`videoimage` FROM `videolist` WHERE `tags` = ? ";
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$sexy);
        //$stmt->bindValue(":limitz",4,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        //$stmt->bindValue(":isi",1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){

            $stmt->bind_result($videoname,$username,$videourl,$uploaddate,$duration,$views,$tags,$videoimage);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $descBox = $doc->getElementById('suggested-video');

                //create the element to append to #element1
                $appended = $doc->createElement('li', "
                        <a href='video.php?watch=$videourl'>
                            <li>
                                <div class='leftside'>
                                    <img src='' width='100%' height='100%' style='background-color: blue;' >                    
                                </div>

                                <div class='rightside'>
                                    <h4>$videoname</h4>
                                    <p>$username</p>
                                    <p>$views views</p>
                                    <p>$duration</p>                    
                                </div>

                            </li>
                        </a>

                ");

                //actually append the element
                $descBox->appendChild($appended);

            }
            echo $doc->saveHTML();
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
echo html_entity_decode($doc->saveHTML());
```

Comment: just one more question. the li element that is created did not seem to be effected by css. instead of becoming <li><a href ....> </li> it seem to turned out to be like this <a href....> cause it didnt get effected by display:inline-block like it should be. why is that?  picture = https://postimg.org/image/4ly7hyopp/

Comment: nvm i found out the problem.